# Hadwiger's conjecture

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if Hadwiger’s conjecture for (r + 1), it must also hold for r. (Hint: you might try to show that r=4 implies r=3 first, to get an idea for what’s at hand.)

I have a rough idea of the proofs for r=3 and r=4, but I am having trouble trying to move on to answer the question. Any thoughts or solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: For those interested, there are [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) such [conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(combinatorial_geometry)).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $G$ has a $K_r$ minor. Create a new graph $G'$ by adding a new vertex $v$ to $G$ that is adjacent to all vertices in $G$. What can you say about $G'$? What kind of minor must it have? What does this mean about its chromatic number? What does that say about $G$?

Comment: After some thought I think I still might be having trouble with seeing it.

Comment: @Lindsey Ok, you're assuming that if a graph has a $K_{r+1}$ minor, its chromatic number must be at least $r+1$ (Hadwiger's for $r+1$). Now you want to prove that if a graph $G$ has a $K_r$ minor, its chromatic number must be at least $r$. Suppose $G$ has a $K_r$ minor. Create $G'$ like I did above. Can you apply Hadwiger's conjecture for $r+1$ to $G'$? And what does it tell you about $G$?

Comment: If it's adjacent to all the vertices wouldn't you have to color it with r+1 colors because the vertex is the +1 meaning if you remove the vertex the graph can be colored with r colors.

Comment: @Lindsey It sounds like you're on the right track. By adding the vertex, there is a $K_{r+1}$ minor, so $G'$ can be colored in at most $r+1$ colors, which means $G$ can be colored in at most $r$ colors.

Comment: Is there anything else I am missing or that I should consider when writing the proof formally?

Comment: @Lindsey You might want to add some details on why you know there is a $K_{r+1}$ minor, and why $G$ can be colored in at most $r$ colors, just to show your understanding (if this is for a class).

Comment: @PerryElliottIverson If we add the vertex and it is adjacent to all the vertices since we know that G has a K$_r$ minor then with edge contraction we now have to have a K$_r+1$ minor? And G can be colored at most with r colors because K$_r$ can be colored with r colors so if we add back vertices and edges then there is a possibility for a smaller amount of colors, but we certainly do not need larger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21014/discussion-between-perry-elliott-iverson-and-lindsey).